# Quarkus static content response filter

Tags: java, quarkus-reactive

Is there a way to add a filter/interceptor to static resources served from `META-INF/resources`?

I seem have tried all the possible options: `@ServerResponseFilter`, `ContainerResponseFilter`,`WriterInterceptor` however all these functions are called only for `@Path` or `@Route`...

Is there anything similar to [@RouteFilter](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#intercepting-http-requests) but for response?

Comment: But this would essentially make those resources non-static (as it would let you transform them on the fly). If you only want to influence cache-control response headers, i think it would be easier to configure them at a reverse-proxy (ingress) level

Comment: @MichailAlexakis yes, that makes sense, i'm referencing them as `static` only because quarkus calls them as so but what i need is basically a transformer for `META-INF/resources`, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be nothing built-in to modify the response of a static content for now but nothing stops you from serving content in a dynamic way:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class FrontendController {

    @GET
    public Response index() throws IOException {
        try (var index = getClass().getResourceAsStream(FrontendConstants.INDEX_RESOURCE)) {
            if (index == null) {
                throw new IOException("index.html file does not exist");
            }

            //modify index

            return Response
                .ok(index)
                .cacheControl(FrontendConstants.NO_CACHE)
                .build();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{fileName:.+}")
    public Response staticFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (var file = FrontendController.class.getResourceAsStream(FrontendConstants.FRONTEND_DIR + "/" + fileName)) {
            if (file == null) {
                return index();
            }

            var contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(file);

            return Response
                .ok(
                    new String(file.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    contentType == null ? MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN : contentType
                )
                .cacheControl(FrontendConstants.NO_CACHE)
                .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are the only ones available:

```
public interface ClientRequestFilter {
    void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException;
}

public interface ClientResponseFilter {
    void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext,
        ClientResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException;
}

public interface ContainerRequestFilter {
    void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException;
}

public interface ContainerResponseFilter {
    void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
    ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException;
}

public interface ReaderInterceptor {
    Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context)
        throws java.io.IOException, javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
}

public interface WriterInterceptor {
    void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
        throws java.io.IOException, javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
}
```

You could try with `ClientResponseFilter` and see:

> In the Client API, a ClientRequestFilter is executed as part of the
> invocation pipeline, before the HTTP request is delivered to the
> network.
>
> ClientResponseFilter is executed upon receiving a server response,
> before control is returned to the application.

https://quarkus.io/specs/jaxrs/2.1/index.html#filters_and_interceptors

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Tried all of them with debugger and none gets executed for static content, only for routes from java code

Comment: @SamIvichuk Unfortunately these are the only filters, so if you are not able to see your full path resource as part of the intercept, then there is no other way.

Comment: Got it, thank you SMA!